# 2020 Census - Geoids don't match?

Tags: census

I've downloaded the data for table H3 for the 2020 decennial census from data.census.gov for zip code tabulation area and then zip code tabulation area shapefile from the census tiger website. Their documentation says the geoids should match to relate them but they're different. It looks like after US in the data geoid matches the shapefile geoid but I don't want to manipulate the data without official instructions to do so. I just can't find anything. Has anyone run into this?

Geoid from data for ZCTA5 00601: 860Z200US00601
Geoid from shapefile for 00601: 00601